# Issue in installing oracle 18cxe on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, ubuntu-18.04, lib, linux-disk-free

I am trying to configure Oracle XE but am facing the below issue:

> root@venky-Lenovo-G510:~# /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
>
> /bin/df: unrecognized option '--direct' 
>      Try '/bin/df --help' for more information.
>      Specify a password to be used for database accounts.
>      Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8
>      characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower
>
> case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be
>
> used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:
>      Confirm the password:
>      Configuring Oracle Listener. Listener configuration succeeded.
>      Configuring Oracle Database XE.
>      ****[FATAL] [DBT-50000] Unable to check for available memory.****
>
> Database configuration failed. Check logs under
>   '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca'.
>
> root@venky-Lenovo-G510:~#

Is this anything related to `/bin/df: unrecognized option '--direct'` ?
Or something else ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you might have some dependencies missing ... binutils springs to mind.

Comment: I'm not sure Oracle 18c XE is supported on Ubuntu.  It doesn't appear on the list of supported distributions here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0

Comment: i have converted the rpm to deb and installed it

Answer (score 22):

Thanks to alexsander-perusso's answer above, the correct answer for oracle-xe-18c on Ubuntu **16.04** is to edit `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c` by adding

```
-J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false
```

on the line directly below `echo "Configuring Oracle Database $ORACLE_SID."` after `$PDB_NAME`.

Here is what the line looks like **after** the edit:

```
$SU -s /bin/bash  $ORACLE_OWNER -c "(echo '$ORACLE_PASSWORD'; echo '$ORACLE_PASSWORD'; echo '$ORACLE_PASSWORD') | $DBCA -silent -createDatabase -gdbName $ORACLE_SID -templateName $TEMPLATE_NAME -characterSet $CHARSET -createAsContainerDatabase $CREATE_AS_CDB -numberOfPDBs $NUMBER_OF_PDBS -pdbName $PDB_NAME -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false -sid $ORACLE_SID -emConfiguration DBEXPRESS -emExpressPort $EM_EXPRESS_PORT -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.DBCredentials=false -sampleSchema true $SQLSCRIPT_CONSTRUCT $DBFILE_CONSTRUCT $MEMORY_CONSTRUCT"
```

Reference: http://www.eygle.com/archives/2018/11/oracle_18c_19c_dbt_50000.html

I was following the instructions here: https://tec600.wordpress.com/2017/06/29/oracle-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04/ with changes for 18c XE

Results after the above changes:

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
/bin/df: unrecognized option '--direct'
Try '/bin/df --help' for more information.
Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:
Confirm the password:
Configuring Oracle Listener.
Listener configuration succeeded.
Configuring Oracle Database XE.
Enter SYS user password: 
*******
Enter SYSTEM user password: 
*******
Enter PDBADMIN User Password: 
*********
Prepare for db operation
7% complete
Copying database files
29% complete
Creating and starting Oracle instance
30% complete
31% complete
34% complete
38% complete
41% complete
43% complete
Completing Database Creation
47% complete
50% complete
Creating Pluggable Databases
54% complete
71% complete
Executing Post Configuration Actions
93% complete
Running Custom Scripts
100% complete
Database creation complete. For details check the logfiles at:
 /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/XE.
Database Information:
Global Database Name:XE
System Identifier(SID):XE
Look at the log file "/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/XE/XE.log" for further details.

Connect to Oracle Database using one of the connect strings:
     Pluggable database: SERVERNAME:1539/XEPDB1
     Multitenant container database: SERVERNAME:1539
Use https://localhost:5500/em to access Oracle Enterprise Manager for Oracle Database XE
```

Comment: Does anyone know the equivalent fix for installing on Windows 10 Pro ?

Comment: the same modification works with **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** as well.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to edit the script file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c
```

And add the Java class:

```
-JDoracle.assistants.dbca.validade.ConfigurationParams=false
```

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcZLD2l6WTw

Comment: You got a typo there -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false